# How to switch control from a second window to the third window in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Actually , in my website i am having around 7,8 windows . I have switched control from window 1 to window 2 through window handler . But now how to switch control from second to third , third to fourth and so on .

Please help me in this situation . I used the following code to switch control from first window to second , but the same code is not working for second to third , third to fourth and so on :-

String window1 = driver.getWindowHandle();

```
for (String window2 : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(window2); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
}
```

Comment: Have a read through [Ask]. Post some code to show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned any language. I will give you a java code:

```
for (String windowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {

    // Switches to pop-up window
    driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);

}
```

The above code will always switch to the last window opened by webdriver. Lemme know if this works for you.

Comment: This is switching control from my first window to second window , but when i am using same code to switch control to upcoming windows  , then this code is not working . There are successive windows one by one as i have mentioned .